# What is the process to use previously-deployed POI devices in a PCI P2PE solution?

Tags: pci-dss

One question for the FAQ "[What is the process to use previously-deployed POI devices in a PCI P2PE solution?](https://pcissc.secure.force.com/faq/articles/Frequently_Asked_Question/What-is-the-process-to-use-previously-deployed-POI-devices-in-a-PCI-P2PE-solution?q=What%20is%20the%20process%20to%20use%20previously-deployed%20POI%20devices%20in%20a%20PCI%20P2PE%20solution&l=en_US&fs=Search&)" .

In the following case, does "reload cryptographic keys" mean that should load POI's new Initial Terminal Master Key to the POI devices using asymmetric key-loading techniques or manual techniques?

Is it acceptable to only just replace existing TMK with the new TMK using standard symmetric-key-exchange mechanism to "reload cryptographic keys" in the following case?

*If the solution provider lacks sufficient evidence to verify the applicable P2PE requirements have been satisfied (as determined by a P2PE Assessor during the course of a P2PE assessment), then all firmware, cryptographic keys, configurations, and software must be reloaded into the POI devices in accordance with applicable P2PE requirements.*

Answer (score 1):

This can be complex and so for certainty you need to ask the P2PE QSA. The objective is to ensure the integrity of the POI and its associated keys. If the key update is compliant with the key management requirements of P2PE and the initial key injection was completed in a P2PE validated environment following validated processes then it will generally be OK, BUT because each POI vendor and solution provider has their own way of doing things, only a P2PE QSA familiar with the solution can give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the provenance of the device's asymmetric keys can be verified to adhere to key management requirements of Domain 6 and Domain 6 Annex A, the device would need to be returned to a Key Injection Facility and new keys injected.

The new keys to be injected would likely be new symmetric keys to facilitate remote key injection in the future. The Initial Key for derivation of future keys for PAN encryption can also be injected in the KIF or later through asymmetric distribution.

Due to how onerous a task it is to return a full POI estate for re-keying, the PCI SSC have an assessment available called the Non-Listed Encryption Solution Assessment. This is known as NESA - for reference, see https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/Assessment_Guidance_Non-Listed_Encryption_Solutions.pdf

The NESA can allow for scope reduction in a merchant environment even if not all P2PE requirements are adhered to. A P2PE QSA must assess the risk in terms of the non-compliant elements but Domains 5 and 6 do need to be fully in place.